# Updating magento by composer error

Tags: magento2.3, composer

I'm trying to update a magento2.3.4 store to magento2.3.6-p1 using composer,
`composer-1 require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.6-p1`
What could it be? any help is appreciated...
[image: error composer]

update: I edited all the composer.json file with the correct specifications to magento2.3.6-p1, and when a run `composer-1 update` it returns:

[image: erro update]

Comment: How Your composer.json looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that removing the "replace" array from composer.json file.